# Why was my answer removed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, specific-answer

My [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687534/group-by-range-in-mysql/13186519#13186519) was removed, but there are no comments or other information about why.

I was correcting an incorrect answer, which is still there and still incorrect.  I can't provide comments on a post yet due to my new account.

No information was provided about why it was removed. Should I expect to see something?
It did get a vote up.

Comment: It is possible it was removed as a "Late Answer" by a less than observant reviewer.

Comment: It seems like you are addressing one of the other answers rather than the question.

Answer (score 14):

You weren't answering the question, you were replying to another answer. You can't do that with an answer, that is what comments are for. If you don't have permission to post comments yet, your option is to remain silent, *not* to flaunt the rules and abuse the question/answer system. We specifically disallow 1-rep users from posting comments. You'll have to wait until you gain this privilege through the proper channels.

Comment: Mind you, if he has a *better* version of the answer he was replying to he can post it *as an answer*.

Comment: The other answer is incorrect.  What is the correct way to fix this, or is it better to just abide by the rules and leave an incorrect answer in place?

Comment: You can post an independent answer and it's allowed to refer to other answers. So your post was kind of OK, just a bad opening sentence and a hasty moderator.

Comment: Is it kosher to simply re-post it (with improved wording)?

Comment: @Josh Just edit your post into a stand-alone answer and flag it (or @ reply to me here) and a moderator will undelete it.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard Done, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I can see your deleted post and to me, its much more of a reply which should be a comment.